# Can I debug an application which is running on other eclipse instance?

Tags: eclipse

I have two eclipse instances running.

- And in one I have the code base.
- And in other eclipse i am running the application.

So can I debug this application in the eclipse where I have code base?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine your build produces a JAR file? if so, then you can run the JAR from the console and then plug the eclipse debugger.

Check [this tutorial](http://eclipse.dzone.com/articles/how-debug-remote-java-applicat), that is clear and with screenshots

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to launch a remote debug session

1/ Specify the following option when launching the app from the first eclipse

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000
```

2/ Launch a Remote Java App (`Run > Debug> Debug Configurations... > Remote Java Application`.)

```
 -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000
```

(if `port 8000` is free) in order to debug the app from the "code base" eclipse.
See [Remote Debugging with Eclipse](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t53459.html).

You can specify the sources in the Remote Java App configuration by referencing your own code base.

[image: Eclipse Remote Debug]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can attach the debugger to a remote JVM. See [How to attach debugger to running process?](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg25518.html)